# Blur on three.js reflector object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I recently started working on a configurator tool, and I need a reflective surface on the ground to reflect the object we want to showcase and create a studio-like appearance.

The problem is that Three.js has a version of reflector, but its a 1:1 reflection and it looks weird since its too reflective. The question is if anyone knows how I can make that reflected image slightly more blurry. I'm not that well versed in shaders...

Alternatively, if there are better ways I am open to changing my approach. I am looking for the most performant way of getting a similar result to a car showcase. Image for reference
https://comps.canstockphoto.com/3d-red-hot-rod-drawing_csp0608954.jpg

Link to the file I am using.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/objects/Reflector.js

and the code I use to place it in the scene:

```
        var mirrorGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(200, 200);
        var groundMirror = new Reflector(mirrorGeometry, {
            clipBias: 0.05,
            textureWidth: window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,
            textureHeight: window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio,
            color: 0x777777,
            recursion: 1
        });
        scene.add(groundMirror);
```

tl;dr: Object is placed on a mirror, causing an identical reflection. Which looks weird for a showcase model. I am asking for information on how to blur it, but a different approach would also work for me.

Edit: Apparently the Reflector object can also not receive shadows (though I need to look into this first. This is also a factor in the final render)

Comment: Greetings and welcome to Stack Overflow! can you please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Appologies, I went home for the day after posting the message. Maybe I should keep track of things when I open a topic. Though I couldn't have provided much info from home... 

The kind of exact code I am using is on this HTML page https://threejs.org/examples/?q=mirror#webgl_mirror. It is the same system. I will try and make a JSFiddle so you can see only what is required for my problem.

Comment: In the meantime while I try and make a working web example, I ve extracted what would be useful from my scene setup. https://pastebin.com/ifn0059E. I am rather new to JS in general and am having a bit of trouble getting my assets to load in a JSFiddle...